# Linking Armadillo and OpenBlas on Windows 10

Tags: g++, armadillo, openblas

Beginner here so apologies if the question is basic or poorly organized.

I am trying to link Armadillo 10.3.0 to OpenBlas 0.3.13 on Windows 10 using the pre-compiled OpenBlas [here](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/releases/tag/v0.3.13) and am running into undefined reference issues.

When I compile my C++ using `g++ my_script.cpp -o my_script -I "C:/.../armadillo-10.3.0/include" -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -L "C:/.../armadillo-10.3.0/examples/lib_win64/libopenblas.dll" -I "C:/.../boost_1_75_0"`, it works perfectly when `my_script.cpp` only includes basic Arma operations.

However, if I add certain Arma operations (e.g., `chol`, `mvnrnd`) I run into several **undefined reference to `xxx'** issues (see example below) when I try to compile:

```
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\12\cc0AVY6p.o:my_script.cpp:
(.text$_ZN4arma6lapack5syevdIdEEvPcS2_PiPT_S3_S5_S5_S3_S3_S3_S3_[_ZN4arma6lapack5syevdIdEEvPcS2_PiPT_S3_S
5_S5_S3_S3_S3_S3_]+0x83): undefined reference to `dsyevd'
```

I have tried:

- Playing around with `armadillo_bits/config.hpp` to adjust flags per [here](https://fossies.org/linux/armadillo/README.md)
- Checking `arma::arma_config` to see if `.blas` and `.lapack` are true / enabled after compiling the version of `my_script.cpp` without the troublesome Arma operations (they are true/enabled)

If anyone has any thoughts on this would appreciate any guidance, thanks!

Comment: There is a difference between the `-L` and `-l` options to gcc (uppercase and lowercase versions of L). `-L` specifies the path (folder). `-l` specifies the library. So try using this: `g++ my_script.cpp -o my_script -O2 -I "C:/.../armadillo-10.3.0/include" -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -L "C:/.../armadillo-10.3.0/examples/lib_win64/" -l libopenblas -I "C:/.../boost_1_75_0"`. Also don't forget to enable optimization with `-O2`

Comment: Ah makes sense, thanks! I updated the g++ to reflect the above and it was able to compile (which is an improvement). New issue is that when I run the compiled executable, it claims to not find ``libopenblas.dll`` even though ``libopenblas.dll`` is stored in the path corresponding to the ``-L`` flag.

I can mess around with it as this might be separate though

Comment: Maybe also try liking with `libopenblas.lib` instead of `libopenblas.dll`.  The former is probably a stub for loading the latter at runtime. Windows is notorious for having very primitive handling of shared libraries.

Comment: I tried that but it did not end up working. I just got it to work and the solution was putting ``libopenblas.dll`` in the same directory as my compiled .exe.

Thanks for the help on this!